# How to create database on google cloud sql instance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

How can I use Cloud SQL to create a database? When I use MySQL, I could easily run a sql script to create them on phpMyAdmin.

I found a [site](http://novelcode.blogspot.com/2013/07/phpmyadmin-on-google-app-engine-part-2_16.html) that advertises that it's possible to run SQL files right on Google Cloud SQL.

[image: google run SQL files image]

This is *exactly* what I want to do. I could run my code to create a couple databases, and they would be in my cloud SQL, and I could connect my appengine app to my cloudsql and it would work as expected.

But when I follow the instructions on that site, I only see this:

[image: actual cloud SQL site image]

Where is the SQL prompt? How can I create databases on my cloud sql instance?

Answer (score 15):

As [@Juan Enrique Muñoz Zolotoochin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128412/juan-enrique-mu%C3%B1oz-zolotoochin) says, singe February 2015 it is now possible to manage databases using the new [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com), making my original answer (below) obsolete.

#### New Answer

Open your project, expand **Storage** and then **Cloud SQL**, switch to the **DATABASES** tab. From there you can use the **New database** button to create a new database. You can also delete databases from there.

#### Original Answer (Now obsolete)

This has not been implemented in the new Cloud Console yet, you have to use the old api's console for this.

To get to it first go to the Cloud SQL section of your project in the new console (where you are). Then in the bottom right there is a link "Return to original console". If you click on this you get to a slightly different control panel for Cloud SQL.

If you then click on the instance you want to create your database on, you will get another screen that has a "SQL Prompt" tab, click on that and then you can execute raw SQL commands against it.

UPDATE: To get to the old APIs console and prevent the redirect taking you to the new console use this link: https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect

Comment: I haven't found link to Access the API's Console under the Cloud SQL in new Console. Can explain elaborate?

Comment: Looks like Google modified the console since I originally answered this, the link has been moved, I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Great answer, especially for those of us with an ISP who don't support IPV6 for some reason.

Comment: @DavidYell If you need an IPv4 access, you can request one, either during instance creation (Click **Show advanced options...** scroll down, Then under **IPv4 ADDRESS** there is an **Assign an IPv4 address...** option). Or on existing instances (under **ACCESS CONROL**, you can **Request IPv4 address**). In both cases note that you will be charged $0.01 for each hour that the address is allocated by the instance is inactive , but you could just assign an address whilst you remotely connect to create your database and then de-allocate it once finished.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE (2015-02-13):** You can now use the Developer Console UI to manage your MySQL databases. Just go to your Cloud SQL instance page and click on the `Databases` tab.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER (still works):** 
If you have a MySQL client installed it is fairly easy to connect to your Cloud SQL instance and create a new Database.

1. Go to the Access Control section of your Cloud SQL instance.
2. If you haven't done it, get an external IP Address.
3. From the same page, set the password for the `root` user.
4. Whitelist yourself by adding a new Authorized Network and entering [your IP](http://www.whatsmyip.org).

Then, if you're using the standard mysql command line client, go a to a terminal and run

```
mysql -uroot -p<your-root-password> -h<your-cloudsql-instance-ip>
```

Or you can just use any client you want.

Once you've connected to you database you can just `CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase`.

Comment: Works perfectly for me following your excellent step-by-step. I use the command-line mysql client all the time, so this is a very easy way for me to get access to the database. Thanks for the tip!!